# get id of url to echo into wordpress shortcode

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a url http://api.spreaker.com/download/episode/3360726.mp3?preroll=0&commercials=0 all O want to do is get the numbers right before the .mp3 so i can add it to a wordpress shortcode. url is coming from a rss feed. you can see example here http://thecasadefe.com/category/blog/spreaker/ right now it working cause I manually input the id in the shortcode but from rss feed i get url but i cant get the id out of url through php to echo into shortcode.

here is my code:

```
    <?php $enclosure = get_post_meta($post->ID , 'enclosure', $single = true);
    $media=explode(chr(10),$enclosure); ?>
    <?php if (!is_null($media)) : ?>
    <?php $url='<a href="'.$media[0].'" rel="nofollow">'.$media[0].'</a>';
    echo($url); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php $mp3title=the_title(); ?>
    <?php $url=''.$mp3title.'';echo($url); ?>
<?php echo do_shortcode("[spreaker type=standard width=100% autoplay=false episode_id=3161467]"); ?>
```

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: this is the shortcode
<?php echo do_shortcode("[spreaker type=standard width=100% autoplay=false episode_id=3161467]"); ?>

Comment: Pretty please, **do not** open and close PHP tags at *each line*. Use it only to switch between PHP and HTML. It's awfully hard to read code this way. Your same code with sane formatting: http://pastebin.com/qcTM0ggM

Answer (score 0):

That's solved with a couple of PHP functions, [`parse_url`](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.parse-url.php) and [`pathinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.pathinfo.php):

```
$url = 'http://api.spreaker.com/download/episode/3360726.mp3?preroll=0&commercials=0';
$parse = parse_url( $url );
/*
$parse = array (size=4)
  'scheme' => string 'http' (length=4)
  'host' => string 'api.spreaker.com' (length=16)
  'path' => string '/download/episode/3360726.mp3' (length=29)
  'query' => string 'preroll=0&commercials=0' (length=23)
*/

$info = pathinfo( $parse['path'] );
/*
$info = array (size=4)
  'dirname' => string '/download/episode' (length=17)
  'basename' => string '3360726.mp3' (length=11)
  'extension' => string 'mp3' (length=3)
  'filename' => string '3360726' (length=7)
*/
$final_id = $info['filename'];
```

Answer (score 0):

could be naughty and use a regex

```
preg_match('~(\d+)(?=\.mp3)~',$url,$matches)
```

then $matches[0] will contain `3360726`